# Pausing loop till user click a button

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface

I have loop like this:

```
do{
    /* method is randomly choosing next question from database */
    /* Question keep possibly answers aswell */
    Question question = questionBase.getNextQuestion(); 

    /* creating new panel with label with question and buttons with answers */
    QuestionPanel qPanel = new QuestionPanel(question);

    /* show panel to user */
    myJFrame.setContentPane(qPanel);
    myJFrame.validate();

    /* wait till user will answer - so when button from panel qPanel is clicked */
    /* how?? */

}while(!isEnd());
```

What i have tried is a simple `while(qPanel.isAnswered() == false())` loop when i was checkign a flag `answered` which was set on true when button was clicked. But Gui is not refreshing at all cuz of while loop

I have tried to put Swing Worker, but my main loop DoWhile is not waiting for his execution, what is reasonable.

I have tried Swing Timer however my main loop is not stoping at all.

Maybe im using it in the wrong way. However, what is best way to solve my problem?

Comment: you need to use threads.or you can ask next question after the user response for a question then you not need thread

Answer (score 1):

> ..what is best way to solve my problem?

- Provide a button for the user to <kbd>lock in answer</kbd> or <kbd>check answer</kbd>
- Add an action listener to the button.
- When the action event is detected, proceed.

(And ignore the advice that you need a thread.  You already have one - the Event Dispatch Thread, and don't need another.)

Comment: correct. totally skipped the part that it was gui and it can have ActionListeners. Nice reminder thanks. will delete the comment instantly

Comment: can u show me how "When the action event is detected" part look like, some tutorial or smth?

Comment: *"can u show me .. some tutorial .."*  Tip:  Put 'X java tutorial' in your favorite search engine, where 'X' might equal what you are researching, e.g. 'action event'.  Follow the top link.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank u for responding Andrew however i asked about any example becouse i can imagine how ActionEvent can help me here. I mean how to implement waiting till ActionEvent is detected without pausing gui aswell.

Comment: I doubt you've had time to read that tutorial and work through the examples.  SO is not a help-desk, in case you are confused.